# Android FacebookSDK get Birthday

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created sample app with facebook sdk integration. Now I can Login with facebook Also get some basic information from facebook. But fail to got birthday from "**GraphUser**" I have noticed that for birthday I need to set permission "**user_birthday**"  which I have already set. I couldn't get what wrong with response.

```
 private static Session openActiveSession(Activity activity, boolean allowLoginUI, Session.StatusCallback callback, List permissions) {
            Session.OpenRequest openRequest = new Session.OpenRequest(activity).setPermissions(permissions).setCallback(callback);
            Session session = new Session.Builder(activity).build();
            if (SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED.equals(session.getState()) || allowLoginUI) {
                Session.setActiveSession(session);
                session.openForRead(openRequest);
                return session;
            }
            return null;
        }
    private void startFacebookLogin() {
        openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                if (session.isOpened()) {
                    //make request to the /me API
                    Log.e("sessionOpened", "true");
                    Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                            if (user != null) {
                                String firstName = user.getFirstName();
                                String lastName = user.getLastName();
                                String id = user.getId();
                                String email = user.getProperty("email").toString();


                                Log.d("AllData", user.toString());

                                Log.e("facebookId", id);
                                Log.e("firstName", firstName);
                                Log.e("lastName", lastName);
                                Log.e("email", email);
                                String Birthdate=user.getBirthday();
                                Log.e("Birthdate", Birthdate+"::Birthdate");



                            }
                        }
                    }).executeAsync();

                }
            }
        },  Arrays.asList(
                new String[] { "email",  "user_location", "user_birthday","user_likes" }));
    }
```

**GraphUser respose is**

```
GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphUser, state={"id":"…..","first_name":"…..","timezone":5.5,"email":"…..@gmail.com","verified":false,"name":"…..","locale":"en_US","link":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/app_scoped_user_id\/....\/","last_name":"…..","gender":"male","updated_time":"2012-12-21T06:54:19+0000"}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying this with an admin/tester/developer user of your Facebook app? If not, the reason is that if you request extended permissions, you'll need to get your app through the Facebook app review process, as described here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login#do-you-need-review

Comment: thanks for answer.. I just visited admin developer account and checking review section Big thanks for answer.. I will accept answer if it works :)

Comment: are you sure we need to review app first ?? because it need so many think to review. APK, images, privacy url etc..

Comment: Like I said, if you test this with an admin/tester/developer, it should be fine.